# Searching for string in SQL table (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: sql, database, search

I am banging my head against the wall with this. I am trying to create a search function for a table in my database. I want to be able to search by ID and by first name + last name.

The search by ID function is working perfect:

```
        if (is_id_search)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
            {
                if (table.Rows[i][0].ToString() == searched_id)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Student With ID: " + searched_id + " Found", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                    display_searched_info(table.Rows[i]);
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (i == (rowcount - 1))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("SEARCH FAILED: Student ID Not Found!", "Search Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I try the same with searching by name it can't match the input string and the value in the table, I have even set a MessageBox to pop up on each iteration of the for loop displaying `row[i][column].ToString()` and it outputs the name I am searching but still says not found (code below):

```
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(table.Rows[i][1].ToString());

                if (table.Rows[i][1].ToString() == searched_Fname)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Student By Name Of: " + searched_Fname + " Found!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == (rowcount - 1))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Student By The Name Of: " + searched_Fname + " " + searched_Lname + " Not Found",
                            "Search Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated (a couple of screenshots below)

[output string from searched column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkAQs.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZp3j.png)

Comment: Do you perhaps have spaces somewhere?

Comment: Yeah that did it. I can't believe it was something so simple haha. I have been on an emotional roller coaster trying get this to work

Comment: It might be better to let your database do the comparison, SQL ignores trailing spaces in most comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing  (table.Rows[i][0].ToString() == searched_Fname) for the String